# load external stylesheet on single component only angular2

Tags: angular

I am trying to use materialize.css along bootstrap.css.

Bootstrap is defined globally in angular.config.

Is there any way i can use materialize.css only in a single component (not globally) and how.

Thanks

Comment: add that stylesheet to the styleUrls array in the component declaration

Comment: can i access assets folder in stylesUrl?

Comment: yes, https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#appendix-loading-with-relative-urls

Comment: Are you using cli?

Comment: i am using angular/cli